# ClojureScript compiler can't find namespace/file in same directory

Tags: clojurescript

`lein cljsbuild` is having trouble finding a namespace/file that's defined right alongside another namespace/file unless I make sure they're compiled in a certain order.

My directory layout looks like this:

```
project/
  project.clj
  src/
    cljs/
      contempo/
        common/
          defs.cljs
        view/
          core.cljs
          navigation.cljs
```

`navigation.cljs` has some stuff to build Om components for navigating around the page, and `core.cljs` is the main entry point for this particular page. `navigation.cljs` starts with:

```
(ns contempo.view.navigation (:require ...))
```

`core.cljs` starts with:

```
(ns contempo.view.core (:require [contempo.view.navigation :as navigation]))
```

When I run `lein cljsbuild`, I get:

```
solace:Groov jfischer$ lein cljsbuild auto
Compiling ClojureScript.
Compiling "war/view/js/app.js" from ["src/cljs/contempo/common" "src/cljs/contempo/view"]...
Compiling "war/view/js/app.js" failed.
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: failed compiling file:src/cljs/contempo/view/core.cljs

... snipped stacktrace ...

Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace: contempo.view.navigation at line 1 src/cljs/contempo/view/core.cljs
```

I can get it to work by removing all references to `contempo.view.navigation` from core.cljs, running `lein cljsbuild auto` and letting the compile finish, then putting them back and saving (so cljsbuild picks up the changes), but that's silly and shouldn't be necessary.

My `project.clj` looks like:

```
(defproject contempo "0.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Experimenting with ClojureScript and Om"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2740"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "0.8.7"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]]

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["war/view/js/app.js"
                                    "war/view/js/out"]

  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "view-dev"
                        :source-paths ["src/cljs/contempo/common"
                                       "src/cljs/contempo/view"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "war/view/js/app.js"
                                   :output-dir "war/view/js/out"
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   :cache-analysis true
                                   :source-map true}}]})
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong? This looks pretty similar to every ClojureScript project I've looked at.

Update: Tiny skeleton project that shows the error is up here: [namespace-error-demo.zip](http://www.mohiji.org/files/namespace-error-demo.zip)

Comment: Works for me without errors/warnings. I suspect that either you have circular dependencies or one of the source files fail to compile. Also, it might be worth trying using single source path `"src/cljs/contempo/"`

Comment: Checked for circular dependencies, collapsed it down to just one source-path, and actually removed almost all the code, and I still get the error.

A tiny project that demonstrates it is available here: [namespace-error-demo.zip](http://www.mohiji.org/files/namespace-error-demo.zip)

Comment: I just downloaded and compiled the demo without problems. Try with `lein clean`. If that doesn't work go to your `~/.m2/` directory and delete your Clojurescript and Clojure dependencies, they might be in a bad state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue ended up being: I wasn't obeying the rules for how namespaces are resolved.

With source paths of `src/cljs/contempo/common` and `src/cljs/contempo/view`, if I required the `contempo.view.whatever` namespace, the compiler would look for it at `src/cljs/contempo/common/contempo/view/whatever.cljs` and `src/cljs/contempo/view/contempo/view/whatever.cljs`.

I had to use `src/cljs` as the source directory. What I wanted to pull off (leaving out code for a given page that didn't need it) was kind of silly (since it'd be pulling in all of ClojureScript anyway) and is now properly addressed thanks to [proper Google Closure Module support in ClojureScript](http://swannodette.github.io/2015/02/23/hello-google-closure-modules/).

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem all of today. In my case, the root cause was having .cljs files with "-" in the name. I only discovered this was the problem after switching to 0.0-3030, which provides better error messages for the strict file path to namespace conventions that more recent versions of the cljs compiler have.

You might want to try changing `:source-paths` to `["src/cljs"]`

Comment: Thanks so much! I was having the exact same problem and couldn't figure it out without your comment!